# unable to find style toolbar searchtextfield in skin darkskin used

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I was following a unity 10hr beginner course by Code Monkey and ended up in this error while I was refactoring my code with the new input system. While saving the bindings it showed "unable to find style toolbar searchtextfield in skin darkskin used" I ignored it and moved forward. While executing the code this error showed in the console (attached in the picture). Please help me, i dont know where i ended up wrong or is it a unity bug.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I tried debugging every single line i also deleted and reinstalled unity twice once with the same version and the second time with a older version but nothing solved.

Comment: https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/warning-unable-to-find-style-toolbarseachtextfieldpopup-in-skin-darkskin-logged-in-console-when-opening-in-search Apparently it's a bug that's being fixed.

Comment: As a heads up, please don't screenshot code. It's unpleasant to work with.

Answer (score 3):

According to Unity this has been fixed, but it hasn't been fixed as of 2022.3.4f1 -> exact same situation this side. I realize this isn't helpful in fixing the behavior, but nevertheless I thought it might be useful to someone to know that it is indeed a Unity issue.

https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/warning-unable-to-find-style-toolbarseachtextfieldpopup-in-skin-darkskin-logged-in-console-when-opening-in-search

[Image of Bug Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3mUY.png)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution but im not sure if it is going to affect my game on the long run but i clicked on the warning and it took me to the script that is making the issue and it's becasue they miss spelled "ToolbarSearchTextField" with missing "r" on "search" , however   :
[Initial Script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Zmpe.png)

i removed the read only becasue in wont let you fix the spelling unless you do and change it to "ToolbarSearchTextField" and it Worked :D.
[Edited Script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGL0n.png)